# Java CSV data into array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist, split

I'm having some trouble trying to turn an excel file into an arraylist or just an array containing information stored in different cells.
The information is stored in excel like this example:

> Owner's info ; Car's Owner ; Car's seller;
>
> Date; Car brand ; Number of doors ; Car license plate ; Car color ;
>   Price
>
> 2.3.2013 ; Fiat ; 4 ; 23-21-AA ; black ; 10.000
>
> 2.1.2014 ; Renault ; 4 ; 23-12-BA ; blue ; 25.000

I will need to access information such as getBrand() , getLicense etc, so I wanted to store this different information into arraylists, OwnerInfo[ Owner[] , Seller[] ]
Later I would like to sum the car prices or something else, and because of that I'd like to access CarInfo[6] and sum them all.

I'm kinda lost on this, need some suggestions or tips.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                "file.csv");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] tokens = strLine.split(";");

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) { 
                System.out.println(tokens[i]);
            }
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Another question is when I use

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) { 
    System.out.println(tokens[0]);
}
```

It will print first column of excel (.csv) , but if I print tokens[1] it won't print anything. Why's that?

Also, if I do the same thing on a .txt file it will print the second "column".

Comment: What I see is you are splitting on a **;** while you are using a csv which means your seperator is a comma **,**

Comment: It seems to be only "working" when I use ";" as the separator though

Comment: Can you try to save the excel as csv and then open the csv file in notepad using the open with option. Then add the information to your post that would help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could re-consider your "design". Now what you are doing is, store each line in a java array. This is not convenient for you later processing (as you described).

You can think about the following two alternatives:

- If you love array, you can build a `map<String, String[] (or number)>`  the first string, is the label of your header line, like `number of door`, `car owner...` of course you can use some short name for that., and the arrays, are the columns. Thus, if you want some column data, you just `map.get(name)`. If you could use third party lib, consider some extended map type like `multimap` from guava to ease your implementation.
- You can build your own type (class) for each row, like `CarData`, and generate each `CarData` object for each row, pack them into a Collection.  If it was required, you could build some helper method to get the interesting values from the list.

personally I prefer the 2nd one, since it is flexible. Think about if you have requirement in future like sorting (Comparator), outputing line in other format, reporting .....

I hope I understood your problem right and hope the text above helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/CyborTronik/fluent-ssv for transforming CSV to beans. In your case you need to provide values separator to stream builder.
So you will have something like:

```
carsStream = new SsvStreamBuilder<Car>()
  .withSeparator(";")
  .forEntity(Car.class)
  .stream("~/path/to/file");
```

And voila, use stream of beans instead of arrays.